# wildfly crashes with WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting

Tags: wildfly, ubuntu-16.04, connection-refused

I have installed the wildfly application server on Ubuntu 16.04; version: 10.1.0.Final, release-version: 2.2.0.Final

The server is configured with an port-offset of 100 so that:

> Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:10090/management
>
> Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10090

Everything seems to work **for a while**:
The management interface is accessible and I have also deployed a tiny sample application which works correctly (already undeployed, therefore shouldn't be the problem). After some minutes I suddenly get the following:

> jboss-cli.sh[15286]: Failed to connect to the controller: The controller is not available at localhost:**9990**: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:**9990**. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:**9990**. The connection failed: Connection refused

I didn't do anything, just waited. Afterwards the instance seems to be unreachable.

After days of research I'm now ending up with asking you what's wrong with my configuration or what I'm missing.
And what is trying to connect to http-remoting://localhost:**9990** (it's not me) and especially why is it doing so?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's because your management controller is unreachable.
Possible reasons could be either your jboss is down or network is not allowing you to connect to it.
You can check that by typing command: telnet  
It will show you the connection